# Tweet from a Windows Store app

Tags: javascript, twitter, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm trying to post a simple tweet from a Windows 8.1 app written using WinJS. The whole authentication oAuth phase works, including the PIN code authentication process. The problem appears when I try to post a tweet. I use the following url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", with all the parameters (tokens, etc...) verified thanks to the Twitter's oAuth tool.

All these parameters look fine. However, I'm getting the following error message: "Could not authenticate you: code 32.".

Here's my code:

```
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var args = "";

        args += "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + clientID + "\"";
        args += ", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\"";
        args += ", oauth_signature=\"" + encodeURIComponent(signature) + "\"";
        args += ", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"";
        args += ", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\"";
        args += ", oauth_token=\"" + oauth_token + "\"";
        args += ", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

        request.open("POST", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", false);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", args);
        request.send("status=testStatus");
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Done, I forgot it sorry !

Comment: I can't tell what the resolution to your issue is, but I do suggest you take a look at the HttpClient object instead of doing a raw XMLHttpRequest. It has some benefits and if it solves your issue then all the better.